# The entry field cannot be placed in the desired location in tkinter python.

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple code where I have two tabs. I intend to place the second entry field in column number 1 in the second tab. However, no matter what I do, the entry field 2 still appears only in column number 0 in the second tab. Please help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab1, text = "A")
tabControl.pack()

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab2, text = "B")
tabControl.pack()

entry_field_1 = Entry(tab1)
entry_field_1.grid(row=0, column= 0)

entry_field_2= Entry(tab2)
entry_field_2.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rows and columns that are empty have a width or height of zero. If columns 0-999 are all empty, placing something in column 1000 will still result in it appearing on the left as if it was in column 0. It's still technically in column 1000.